# I cannot get a proper image from video capture anymore. Can it be a conflict with the video drivers?

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I have a application in python which I use VideoCapture to display a webcam frame on the screen. It used to work perfectly until suddenly something wents reallly wrong. I'm using the same code and the image seems to be very noisy.

I tried to work with different cameras and the problem is the same, so the problem is not with the camera. I tried the same code in a different computer. And the application seems to work normally. I wrote a very simple code, just to display the webcam frame in the screen and still I have the same issue.

It seems to be a conflict between opencv and my computer configuration. But I'm not able to figure what is going on.

I hope you can help me with this issue.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Oct 10 10:42:38 2019

@author: vitoro
"""

import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('Original video',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The image I get with this code is:

[Video capture result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8vOC.png)

Comment: To test I would suggest removing complexity. So comment out the `if not isopened` statements. Then try separately with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` and `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` . Does either one work?

Comment: I already tested this with no sucess untill now. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Silly, but I have to ask: have you restarted your pc? Does the camera work with other applications?

Comment: Yes, I already tried restarting my pc and the camera work properly in app 'Camera' from Windows. The problem with opencv continues

Comment: Something in the device manager perhaps, but I can't help you there...